# How to make a power point presentation like this

Tags: powerpoint

maybe this is not the correct forum where to post this question, but i've serched for two weeks in the web, without results.

I need to make a kind of power point presentation, something like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELyOd_sJDyA) - do know which program can i use?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, that tool used for this prezentation can be find on

http://prezi.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is called `infographics` and you can use website like [visual.ly/](http://visual.ly/)

Then, you have to do your own effects